# How to pull data from website?

Tags: android

So I have a website that I have certain data on, and I want to read that data in as variables in Android Studio. What would be the best way to go about this?

I can't just pull all the data, just certain lines, but the webpage is very very simple (10 lines total and contains just data).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library and parse the data you need. If you could be more specific like what data are they or at best send a link from that page, perhaps i could help more.